# ftpclient.retreive() function giving false in java

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am using ftp client to download file from ftp in java .So problem is  that ftp is connecting and then when we go for getting file data , it shows 
:550 /file.xml.gz : no such file or directory.

The below is following code that i used:

```
package jobs;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import static org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FtpFunctions 
{
  FTPClient ftp = null;
  private Logger log;

  public FtpFunctions(String host, int port, String username, String password)
    throws Exception
  {
    this.ftp = new FTPClient();
    this.ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

    this.ftp.connect(host, port);
    System.out.println("FTP URL is:" + this.ftp.getDefaultPort());
    int reply = this.ftp.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
    {
      this.ftp.disconnect();
      throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
    }
    this.ftp.login(username, password);
    System.out.print(BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    this.ftp.setFileType(2);
    this.ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
  //  log=Logger.getLogger("ftp status: " + ftp.getStatus());
  }
  public boolean listFTPFiles(String directory, String propFile)
    throws IOException
  {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream iStream = null;
    if (`enter code here`incUtil.inProduction.booleanValue()) {
      iStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../resources/" + propFile);
    } else {
      iStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFile);
    }
    if (iStream != null) {
      prop.load(iStream);
    }
    Set<Object> keys = prop.keySet();
    String dirPath = prop.getProperty("dirPath");
    System.out.println("propFile name :" + propFile);
    System.out.println("Directory path is :" + dirPath);
    System.out.println("keys are :" + keys);
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);
    try
    {


    for (Object k : keys)
    {
      String key = (String)k;
      String fileName = prop.getProperty(key);
     // log=Logger.getLogger("ftp status: " + ftp.getStatus());
      System.out.println(key + ": " + fileName);
      if (fileName.endsWith(".gz"))
      {
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dirPath + fileName);
        String file="/"+fileName;
        System.out.print(file);

        Boolean success=this.ftp.retrieveFile(file, output);
        if(success)
        {
           System.out.println("FTP File downloaded successfully"); 
        }
       // log=Logger.getLogger("false return from ftp.retrieveFile() - code " + ftp.getReplyCode());


        output.close();
      }
    }
     }catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    boolean verificationFilename = false;

    return verificationFilename;
  }

  public void disconnect()
  {
    if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
      try
      {
        this.ftp.logout();
        this.ftp.disconnect();
      }
      catch (IOException localIOException) {}
    }
  }

  public static void invokeFtpFunction(String jobPropFile, String jobType)
  {
    try
    {
      FtpFunctions ftpobj = new FtpFunctions("xxxx.com", 21, "sss", "sadfsa");

      boolean result = ftpobj.listFTPFiles(".", jobPropFile);
      System.out.println(result);
      ftpobj.disconnect();
//      if (jobType.equals("weeklyJob")) {
//        ConfigureJobs.runWeeklyProcess();
//      } else {
//        ConfigureJobs.runDailyProcess();
//      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
220 Service ready for new user.
FTP URL is:21
USER xxxxx
331 User name okay, need password for asdsa.
PASS xxxxx
230 User logged in, proceed.
2TYPE I
200 Command TYPE okay.
propFile name :ftpDailyFile.properties
Directory path is :/home/xxxx/xxxx/Download/
keys are :[file9]
imageDirPath: /home/xxxx/xxxx/croppedImage/
file9: ddf.xml.gz
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (69,46,36,40,149,167).
RETR /ddf.xml.gz
550 /ddf.xml.gz: No such file or directory.
false
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: Did you try to access same file using any ftp client with same credentials? because 550 normally means lacking of permission/access.

Comment: Yes i undertsand the problem with permission, so can you tell me how can i solve this? mena what will be the problem

Comment: Actually, user with which you are trying to access the resource don't have the enough permission to access the resource and only solution of this is to ask ftp server admin to grant access to that user.

Comment: Yes thanks, now i will go for this, because  i did lot of R&D in this, but every i found permission error.So i will ask ftp server  for accessing files